# Subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Which of the following sets are subspaces of R^3?

A.  $\{ (x,y,z)\mid x + y + z = 0 \}$

B.  $\{ (x,y,z) \mid x < y < z \} $

C.  $\{ (7 x  - 5 y, 2 x  - 6 y, 9 x + 6 y ) \mid  x,y \text{ arbitrary numbers}\}$

D.  $\{ (-4, y, z) \mid y, z \text{ arbitrary numbers} \}$

E.  $\{ (x,y,z)  \mid x + y + z = -7 \}$

F.  $\{ (x, y, z) \mid  4 x  - 3 y = 0, 8 x + 7 z = 0\}$

I have tried to prove A and B are subspaces but I am slightly confused how to prove the others are subspaces or not.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $V\subset\mathbb R^3$ is a vector subspace, then necessarily $(0,0,0)$ belongs to $V$, hence B., D. and E. are not subspaces.

$C$ can be written as the range of a linear map while $A$ and $F$ can be written as the kernel of a linear map.

Answer (score 1):

I won't answer the full question, but here is a simple observation: a necessary condition for $E \subset V$ to be a subspace is that $(0,0,0) \in E$. (This is obviously  not sufficient). Therefore, we can rule out B, D, E.